# Running LG UltraFine 5k with additional low DPI screens

Tags: macbook-pro, display, 5k

I have the following hardware:

- 2018 MacBook Pro 13''
- LG UltraFine 5k
- 2 x ThinkVision 1920x1200

Ideally, I would like to connect these 3 screens to my MacBook Pro.

I connected the LG UltraFine 5k on one side of the MacBook Pro, and both ThinkVision screens on the other side.

Currently, I only manage to get a most 2 of the screens running.

Is this a hardware limitation? Or is there a way to get the 3 screens at once.

Comment: I can't find 2018 specs but current 13" only supports 2 external screens.  See tech specs here : https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/

Comment: @lx07 Thanks for you comment. I found the 2018 spec and answered my own question!

Comment: Great answer! Which model LG 5k - there are two Apple shipped - one is Thunderbolt only and the second one is Thunderbolt and USB-C protocol using the same physical connector.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by in the [2018 MacBook Pro 13-inch spec](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP775?locale=en_US), this is not possible. It supports at maximum of 2 external screens:

> ## Video Support
>
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> - One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
> - Up to two displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors